# PHP exit syntax changed to edatait when using vscode

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

So, I have this code

`<?php defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');`

at very top of my code. Then I need to format my code PHP Formatter from vscode marketplace. When I format my code, the `exit` syntax become `edatait` below is my code after formatted,

`<?php defined('BASEPATH') or edatait('No direct script access allowed');`

Am I miss the php 7.x update that `exit` syntax changed to `edatait`? or something wrong with this formatter plugin?.

Comment: Does it change any other `x` to `data`, or is it just in this specific text combination?

Comment: Which exact formatter plugin did you install? Please provide the URL of its page on the VSCode Marketplace website.

Comment: @droopsnoot No, it's just change if I use type that line.

Comment: @kmoser I use this formatter [link](https://github.com/felixfbecker/vscode-php-intellisense.git) and then I changed to this [link](https://github.com/kokororin/vscode-phpfmt.git) both of that formatter give me same results. 

Am I need to change something? but I have fresh installed vscode.